# How to troubleshoot ORA-6502 / ORA-6512 errors?

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus

I am running the below query.

```
declare
i int;
c_limit constant pls_integer default 10000;
TYPE cdr is table of TABLE_0.ENTITY_ID% type;
c_cdrt_tbl cdr;
cursor c_cdr is (select ENTITY_ID from TABLE_0 where TIME < 1577836800 and status = 2);
BEGIN
open c_cdr ;
LOOP
fetch c_cdr bulk collect into c_cdrt_tbl limit c_limit;
exit when c_cdrt_tbl.count =0;
FORALL i in 1..c_cdrt_tbl.count
delete from TABLE_1 where ID=c_cdrt_tbl(i);
delete from TABLE_2 where ID=c_cdrt_tbl(i);
delete from TABLE_3 where ID=c_cdrt_tbl(i);
delete from TABLE_4 where ID=c_cdrt_tbl(i);
delete from TABLE_5 where ID=c_cdrt_tbl(i);
delete from TABLE_6 where ID=c_cdrt_tbl(i);
commit;
END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Receiving the below error:

```
declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: NULL index table key value
ORA-06512: at line 18
```

I am trying to perform cleanup on some tables which are related to one another via the ENTITY_ID (or ID) value. This value is of

```
type Number(38,0)
```

in all the mentioned tables.

There might be something wrong with the declaration of the initial variables, and the error suggests (at least to me) that the output of

```
select ENTITY_ID from TABLE_0 where TIME < 1577836800 and status = 2
```

is null, however it is not, I have double checked.

Note: Time is in epoch format.

Comment: If the intention is to drive six delete statements off the collection, you'll need six `forall` statements, not one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it all without cursor loops (and don't need PL/SQL):

```sql
DELETE FROM TABLE_1
WHERE id IN ( SELECT entity_id FROM table_0 WHERE time < 1577836800 AND status = 2 );

DELETE FROM TABLE_2
WHERE id IN ( SELECT entity_id FROM table_0 WHERE time < 1577836800 AND status = 2 );

DELETE FROM TABLE_3
WHERE id IN ( SELECT entity_id FROM table_0 WHERE time < 1577836800 AND status = 2 );

DELETE FROM TABLE_4
WHERE id IN ( SELECT entity_id FROM table_0 WHERE time < 1577836800 AND status = 2 );

DELETE FROM TABLE_5
WHERE id IN ( SELECT entity_id FROM table_0 WHERE time < 1577836800 AND status = 2 );

DELETE FROM TABLE_6
WHERE id IN ( SELECT entity_id FROM table_0 WHERE time < 1577836800 AND status = 2 );

COMMIT;
```

If you want to do it with a collection then:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_ids SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST;
BEGIN
  SELECT entity_id
  BULK COLLECT INTO v_ids
  FROM   table_0
  WHERE  time < 1577836800 AND status = 2;

  DELETE FROM TABLE_1
  WHERE id IN ( SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE(v_ids) );

  DELETE FROM TABLE_2
  WHERE id IN ( SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE(v_ids) );

  DELETE FROM TABLE_3
  WHERE id IN ( SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE(v_ids) );

  DELETE FROM TABLE_4
  WHERE id IN ( SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE(v_ids) );

  DELETE FROM TABLE_5
  WHERE id IN ( SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE(v_ids) );

  DELETE FROM TABLE_6
  WHERE id IN ( SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE(v_ids) );

  COMMIT;
END;
/
```

or, if you wanted to use batches:

```sql
DECLARE
  CURSOR c_rec IS
    SELECT entity_id
    FROM   table_0
    WHERE  time < 1577836800 AND status = 2; 

  v_ids SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST;
BEGIN
  OPEN c_rec;
  LOOP
    EXIT WHEN c_rec%NOTFOUND;
    FETCH c_rec BULK COLLECT INTO v_ids LIMIT 10000;

    DELETE FROM TABLE_1
    WHERE id IN ( SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE(v_ids) );

    DELETE FROM TABLE_2
    WHERE id IN ( SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE(v_ids) );

    DELETE FROM TABLE_3
    WHERE id IN ( SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE(v_ids) );

    DELETE FROM TABLE_4
    WHERE id IN ( SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE(v_ids) );

    DELETE FROM TABLE_5
    WHERE id IN ( SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE(v_ids) );

    DELETE FROM TABLE_6
    WHERE id IN ( SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE(v_ids) );
  END LOOP;

  COMMIT;
END;
/
```

If you want to fix yours then you need to use `FORALL` for each delete:

```sql
declare
  c_limit constant pls_integer default 10000;
  TYPE cdr is table of TABLE_0.ENTITY_ID% type;
  c_cdrt_tbl cdr;
  cursor c_cdr is 
    select ENTITY_ID
    from   TABLE_0
    where  TIME < 1577836800
    and    status = 2;
BEGIN
  open c_cdr ;
  LOOP
    fetch c_cdr bulk collect into c_cdrt_tbl limit c_limit;
    exit when c_cdrt_tbl.count =0;
    FORALL i in 1..c_cdrt_tbl.count
      delete from TABLE_1 where ID=c_cdrt_tbl(i);
    FORALL i in 1..c_cdrt_tbl.count
      delete from TABLE_2 where ID=c_cdrt_tbl(i);
    FORALL i in 1..c_cdrt_tbl.count
      delete from TABLE_3 where ID=c_cdrt_tbl(i);
    FORALL i in 1..c_cdrt_tbl.count
      delete from TABLE_4 where ID=c_cdrt_tbl(i);
    FORALL i in 1..c_cdrt_tbl.count
      delete from TABLE_5 where ID=c_cdrt_tbl(i);
    FORALL i in 1..c_cdrt_tbl.count
      delete from TABLE_6 where ID=c_cdrt_tbl(i);
    commit;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: Hi! Wouldn't that take longer? Some tables are really big, up to 2.5 TB.

Comment: @Indru Added various other options.

Comment: thank you for the proposals, I will try these and see which works for me best.

Comment: @Indru Added a fourth option to fix your code. `FORALL` applies to only the next statement so your later `DELETE` statements were referencing `i` from the outer scope (which was uninitialised) and not the collection index.